# How to search for photo using caption

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, search, photo

I'm new to Facebook API coding, so thanks in advance for patience with my question :)

I want to know if there is any way for me to search through users' photos and the users' friends' photos based on caption information.

For example, if I search for "Toyota", I would like my program to search all of my photos as well all the photos of my friends and look for a text match for "Toyota" in the caption of all the photos. I would like to retrieve the photo ID and its caption for subsequent displaying.

Can this be done? Either with https://graph.facebook.com/search?q or with FQL? Of course, we are assuming all authentication has been done and whatever permissions are needed for the application have been granted by the user of the application.

Or would I just need to retrieve all photo captions and then do the searching/filtering on my own in the backend?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FQL you can search only on indexed columns. So i am not sure if the name column i.e. caption of photo is indexed or not. You need to verify this.

Second option of retrieving all photo caption and then doing search will be better as it will be independent of any Change that FB may do to their platform in future.

Hope this helps

Thanks

Kaushik

Comment: Thanks for the help. I had figured these would be my only options. Unfortunately, the caption column is not indexed, so I'll likely need to rely on the second option. Thanks for the help.